# How to use custom reference resolving with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
{
           "id" : "2"
   "categoryId" : "35"
         "type" : "item"
         "name" : "hamburger"
}
{
           "id" : "35"
         "type" : "category"
         "name" : "drinks" 
}
```

And I want to match it to this object:

```
public class Item 
{
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "categoryId")]
  public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

`Category` is of type `Entity` which has a `string` `Id` property I can access.  I want the "35" object created by the JSON Deserializer to be mapped to the `Category` property in the `Item`.

According [to the documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/PreserveObjectReferences.html), I should use a `IReferenceResolver`.  How would I implement this interface and hook it into the JSON.NET framework?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify a custom IRefenceResover in your JsonSerializerSettings:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings ();
settings.ReferenceResolver = new IDReferenceResolver ();
```

There is an excellent implementation example of [IDReferenceResolver](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/TestObjects/IdReferenceResolver.cs) for objects with a *Guid* **id** property. The reference string is now the object's **id**, which is similar to your use case except that your are using *int* instead of *Guid* types for your id property.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

   namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Tests.TestObjects
   {
    public class IdReferenceResolver : IReferenceResolver
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<Guid, PersonReference> _people = new Dictionary<Guid, PersonReference>();

        public object ResolveReference(object context, string reference)
        {
            Guid id = new Guid(reference);

            PersonReference p;
            _people.TryGetValue(id, out p);

            return p;
        }

        public string GetReference(object context, object value)
        {
            PersonReference p = (PersonReference)value;
            _people[p.Id] = p;

            return p.Id.ToString();
        }

        public bool IsReferenced(object context, object value)
        {
            PersonReference p = (PersonReference)value;

            return _people.ContainsKey(p.Id);
        }

        public void AddReference(object context, string reference, object value)
        {
            Guid id = new Guid(reference);

            _people[id] = (PersonReference)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `CustomCreationConverter<T>` as JsonConverter and override both `Create` and `ReadJson` method.

```
class ItemConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Item> {
        public override Item Create(Type objectType)
        {
                return new Item();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
                JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
                int categoryId = jObject["categoryId"].ToObject<int>();
                Category category = Program.Repository.GetCategoryById(categoryId);

                Item result = (Item)base.ReadJson(jObject.CreateReader(), objectType, existingValue, serializer);
                result.Category = category;

                return result;
        }
}

class Item {
        [JsonProperty("itemName")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        // other properties.
}

class Category {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // other properties.
}

class MockCategoryRepository {
        IList<Category> _repository;

        public MockCategoryRepository()
        {
                _repository = new List<Category>();
                _repository.Add(new Category() { CategoryId = 1, Name = "Drink" });
                _repository.Add(new Category() { CategoryId = 35, Name = "Food" });
                _repository.Add(new Category() { CategoryId = 70, Name = "Fruit" });
        }

        public Category GetCategoryById(int id)
        {
                return _repository.Where(x => x.CategoryId == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }
}

class Program {
        public static MockCategoryRepository Repository { get; private set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Repository = new MockCategoryRepository(); // initialize mock repository

                // sample : json contains two items in an array.
                string jsonString = @"
                [ 
                        { ""categoryId"":""35"", ""itemName"":""Item A"" },
                        { ""categoryId"":""70"", ""itemName"":""Item B"" },
                ]";

                List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jsonString, new ItemConverter());
        }
}
```

### Updated answer :

Solution for condition where `Category` object information is fetched from the same json string.

```
class ItemConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Item> {
        readonly IEnumerable<Category> _repository;

        public ItemConverter(IEnumerable<Category> categories)
        {
                _repository = categories;
        }

        public override Item Create(Type objectType)
        {
                return new Item();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
                JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
                int categoryId = jObject["categoryId"].ToObject<int>();
                Category category = _repository.Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId).SingleOrDefault();

                Item result = (Item)base.ReadJson(jObject.CreateReader(), objectType, existingValue, serializer);
                result.Category = category;

                return result;
        }
}

class Item {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        // other properties.
}

class Category {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // other properties.
}

class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                // sample : json contains items and/or categories in an array.
                string jsonString = @"
                [ 
                        {
                                        ""id"" : ""2"",
                                ""categoryId"" : ""35"",
                                      ""type"" : ""item"",
                                      ""name"" : ""hamburger""
                        },
                        {
                                        ""id"" : ""35"",
                                      ""type"" : ""category"",
                                      ""name"" : ""drinks"" 
                        }
                ]";

                JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

                // Separate between category and item data.
                IEnumerable<JToken> jsonCategories = jsonArray.Where(x => x["type"].ToObject<string>() == "category");
                IEnumerable<JToken> jsonItems = jsonArray.Where(x => x["type"].ToObject<string>() == "item");

                // Create list of category from jsonCategories.
                IEnumerable<Category> categories = jsonCategories.Select(x => x.ToObject<Category>());

                // Settings for jsonItems deserialization.
                JsonSerializerSettings itemDeserializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                itemDeserializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ItemConverter(categories));
                JsonSerializer itemDeserializer = JsonSerializer.Create(itemDeserializerSettings);

                // Create list of item from jsonItems.
                IEnumerable<Item> items = jsonItems.Select(x => x.ToObject<Item>(itemDeserializer));
        }
}
```

Comment: But if a Category is defined elsewhere in the master JSON file, then wouldn't duplicate instances be created for the same Category identity?

Comment: No, because in my sample (in-memory repository), `GetCategoryById` only do searching, not creating new `Category` object. Yes, if your repository is getting information from database (real-life case). All you need is to modify get category algorithm on `ReadJson` method to solve your problem.

Comment: If that was the case, then when a category was created by the JSON deserializer, it would have to be registered with the repository, or when it tried to create one that was already referenced, it would have to use the existing Category instance, correct?  I don't see how your solution solves those two issues.

Comment: Your question is about how to create `Item` object with `Category` property instead of `CategoryId` from json string. You don't give any information on where you get `Category` objects. So, I assume you already fetched a list of category object in your code before you deserialize json string that contains `Item` object information. Can you update your question to give more details if you think my understanding about your question is wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'll update the question.  Thanks so much for your help.