# how to remove $id during JSON serialization

Tags: json.net

I am using NewtonSoft.JSON. When running

```cs
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject)
```

it is adding an `$id` value to my JSON - like this:

```
  "$id": "1",
  "BookingId": 0,
  "CompanyId": 0,
  "IsCashBooking": false,
  "PaymentMethod": 0,
  "IsReferral": false,
  "IsReferralPercent": false,
  "ReferralPaymentType": 0,
  "ReferralDues": 0,
  "PassengerId": 0,
  "DepartmentID": 0,
  "CostCenterID": 0,
  "DeadMiles": 0
```

Can we remove this `$id` with some JsonSerializerSettings or by any other method?

If yes - then how...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I added this code to my WebApiConfig register method and I got rid of all $id in JSON.

```cs
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

Comment: Valid answer if you don't need recursive serialization (serializing a hierarchy). $id is used to preserve the handle so if the element repeats somewhere it wont repeat the data it will just set $ref property of the duplicate to the $id of the original. In that case this property must be set to Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects and Sajid's answer could be used.

Comment: I have deleted my post. I am adding my answer here as a comment. So, it can used as a reference to "parliament" suggestion.

delete myObject.$id;

and that's it.

Answer (score 10):

If for some reason you're using a custom ContractResolver, take a look at this other stack overflow;

[Json.Net adding $id to EF objects despite setting PreserveReferencesHandling to "None"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128689/json-net-adding-id-to-ef-objects-despite-setting-preservereferenceshandling-to)

Comment: This is the only correct answer for me. It solved the problem in two situations: using a SQL server provider as well as the Oracle ODP provider.

Answer (score 6):

To remove the $id in JSON for my web API. I included [JsonObject(IsReference = false)] for my class objects and  [JsonProperty(IsReference = false)] for my properties that are of object types. In my case the RespObj property is generic Type T and could take any object type I pass to it including collections so I had to use [JsonProperty(IsReference = false)] to get rid of the $id in the serialized JSON string.

I did not change my WebApiConfig because I was using the MVC help page for WEB API and it required me to have this configuration in my webApiconfig:

```cs
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
        json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
```

The class object

```cs
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[JsonObject(IsReference = false)]
public class QMResponse<T> where T : new()
{
    public QMResponse()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The response code
    /// </summary> 
    public string RespCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The response message
    /// </summary> 
    public string RespMxg { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The exception message
    /// </summary> 
    public string exception { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The object type returned
    /// </summary>         
    [JsonProperty(IsReference = false)]
    public T RespObj { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// No of records returned
    /// </summary> 
    public long RecordCount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Session Object
    /// </summary> 
    public string session_id { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case 'id' is a property of your class then apply [JsonIgnore] attribute on it.
Otherwise probably here is the answer for your question:

http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm

Comment: What about *forcing* NewtonSoft to use either the `id` property value *of* the object *as* the `$id` field, or instead simply use the `id` property for reference handling? This seems like the most logical use, as allowing the serializer to generate it results in different `id`s depending on the total number of graph objects being serialized. (This is a problem if you a serializing objects individually which then need to be assembled into a single object and deserialized)

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus Info on achieving that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237939/how-to-use-custom-reference-resolving-with-json-net

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the basic configuration:

```cs
Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```

I used this code format for my methods

```cs
public JsonResult<T> Get()
{
    return Json(result);
}
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The custom ContractResolver setting overrides the PreserveReferencesHandling setting.

In your implementation of DefaultContractResolver/IContractResolver, add this;

```cs
public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type) {
    var contract = base.ResolveContract(type);
    contract.IsReference = false;
    return contract;
}
```

This behaves similarly to the PreserveReferencesHandling.None setting without a custom ContractResolver