# Content returned from API call

Tags: httpclient, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a netcore api as backend and angular 4 as front end. When I use httpClient get, the call returns the following json.

```
{
 "$id": "242",
 "$values": [
  {
   "$id": "243",
   "name": "AAA",
   "value": 1
  },
  {
   "$id": "244",
   "name": "BBB",
   "value": 8
  },
  ....
}
```

The "$id" changes with every call. Where does the "$id" generate ?

Comment: I think this link answers your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542144/how-to-remove-id-during-json-serialization

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove $id during JSON serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542144/how-to-remove-id-during-json-serialization)