# Controlling JSON .NET's reference ID generation

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reference, json.net

I'd like to be able to control how JSON .NET generates its meta reference IDs such as `"$id": "1"`. Take the following code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person Mother { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
};

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => settings;

var person = new Person
{
    Name = "bob",
    Mother = new Person { Name = "jane" }
};
var personJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
var motherJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person.Mother);
```

The JSON for `person` looks like this:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Name": "bob",
  "Mother": {
    "$id": "2",
    "Name": "jane",
    "Mother": null
  }
}
```

However, if I serialize `person.Mother` directly, the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Name": "jane",
  "Mother": null
}
```

In the first JSON, Jane is `"$id": "2"`, but serializing Jane directly is `"$id": "1"`. This is the behavior I'd expect under normal conditions as the serializer assigns the IDs in the order it traverses the objects, but I'd really like to override the ID generation so that I could make it a hash of the object reference itself. This way, Jane would generate the same ID per running instance of the program every time regardless if serialized as a member of a parent or serialized individually.

**UPDATE**

Per sample code in selected answer and recommendation in comment, I have used `IReferenceResolver`. It turns out that I can't use it, though, but I'll include the code below anyway. The reason why this won't work is because I am trying to bastardize JSON.NET as a quick and dirty cloning tool, so I can't fault it for not suiting my needs. I've since fallen back on my own custom cloning utility, so I no longer need this.

```
public class ObjectReferenceResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.IReferenceResolver
{
    readonly Dictionary<object, int> objectDic = new Dictionary<object, int>();
    int maxId = 0;

    //Called during serialization
    public string GetReference(object context, object value)
    {
        //This method will return the meta $id that you choose. In this example, I am storing
        //object references in a dictionary with an incremented ID. If the reference exists, I
        //return its ID. Otherwise, I increment the ID and add the reference to the dictionary.

        var id = 0;

        if (objectDic.ContainsKey(value))
        {
            id = objectDic[value];
        }
        else
        {
            objectDic[value] = maxId++;
        }

        return id.ToString();
    }

    //Called during serialization
    public bool IsReferenced(object context, object value)
    {
        //Return whether or not value exists in a reference bank.
        //If false, the JSON will return as a full JSON object with "$id": "x"
        //If true, the JSON will return "$ref": "x"
        return objectDic.ContainsKey(value);
    }

    //Called during deserialization
    public void AddReference(object context, string reference, object value)
    {
        //This method is called after the deserializer has created a new instance of the
        //object. At this time, it's only the initial instance and no properties have been set.
        //This method presents a problem because it does not allow you to create the instance or
        //retrieve it from a repo and then return it for later use by the reference resolver.
        //Therefore, I have to find the existing object by $id, remove it, and then add the new 
        //object created by the deseralizer. This creates the possibility for two instances of
        //the same data object to exist within the running application, so, unfortunately, this
        //will not work.

        var e = objectDic.First(x => x.Value.ToString() == reference).Key;

        objectDic.Remove(e);

        objectDic[value] = reference.ParseInt().Value;
    }

    //Called during deserialization
    public object ResolveReference(object context, string reference)
    {
        //This method retrieves an existing reference by $id and returns it.

        var value = objectDic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ToString() == reference).Key;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrianRogers Note that I said "object reference itself". No two objects can share the same reference.

Comment: A custom [`IReferenceResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm#IReferenceResolver) might meet your needs.  See: [How to use custom reference resolving with JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9237939/3744182).

Comment: Did you take a look at [How to use custom reference resolving with JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9237939/3744182)?  If so, is your problem 1) How to generate a unique hash for your objects?  2) How to hook the unique hash into an `IReferenceResolver`?

Comment: Weird, I didn't get a notification for your previous comment. I looked at it, though, and that question appears to be asking how to map `categoryID` in the JSON to the `id` property of a navigation property, something entirely different than what I am asking. I am referring to the `$id` property that exists exclusively in the JSON that the deserializer uses to preserve references. I want to override the value returned by the serializer so that it shows something like `"$id": "whateveriwant"` instead of `"$id": "1"`.

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24125425/3744182) actually shows how to use a Guid as the value of `$id` and `$ref`.

Comment: @dbc I'll take a closer look then. The specificity of the question threw me off, but perhaps they're essentially trying to do what I am doing, but applying a different solution. Some sample JSON in the accepted answer would have been great to show the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per others have recommended, you need a custom [`IReferenceResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IReferenceResolver.htm):

```
class PersonNameAsIdResolver : IReferenceResolver
{
    public void AddReference(object context, string reference, object value)
    {
        // This method is called during deserialize for $id
    }

    public string GetReference(object context, object value)
    {
        // Returns person name as value of $id
        return ((Person)value).Name;
    }

    public bool IsReferenced(object context, object value)
    {
        // Returns false, so that $id is used, not $ref.
        return false;
    }

    public object ResolveReference(object context, string reference)
    {
        // This method is called during deserialize for $ref
        return null;
    }
}
```

To use that:

```
var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
};

settings.ReferenceResolverProvider = ()=> new PersonNameAsIdResolver();
```

**UPDATE**

*Answer to the OP's update*

`AddReference` is called while an object is being populated, so it has been *too late* to replace the object. To be able to find and populate *desired* object, you need a `JsonConverter`, which is called before the reference resolver:

```
class PersonJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly PersonNameAsIdResolver _idResolver;

    public PersonJsonConverter(PersonNameAsIdResolver idResolver)
    {
        _idResolver = idResolver;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        => objectType == typeof(Person);

    // Can't write. There's nothing to changing for writing scenario.
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var obj = (JObject)token;

        // The code below calls the resolver to find the existing instance.
        // This can stop JSON.NET creating a new instance.
        Person instance = null;
        var @id = obj["$id"].Value<string>();
        if (@id != null)
        {
            instance = (Person)_idResolver.ResolveReference(this, @id);
        }
        else
        {
            var @ref = obj["$ref"]?.Value<string>();
            if (@ref != null)
            {
                instance = (Person)_idResolver.ResolveReference(this, @ref);
            }
        }

        // Assuming can't resolve, create a new instance.
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Person();
        }

        // This will populate existing Person object if found
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), instance);

        return instance;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And the default serialization settings should look like:

```
var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
};

var idResolver = new PersonNameAsIdResolver();
settings.Converters.Add(new PersonJsonConverter(idResolver));
settings.ReferenceResolverProvider = () => idResolver;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I marked you as answer and will award the bounty as soon as I am able. Unfortunately, this solution will not work for me. I'll post my code as an answer to the question with an explanation as to why (I am basically trying to bastardize JSON.NET as a quick and dirty cloning method, so I can't fault it for not working as I like).

Comment: @oscilatingcretin See updated. In your case, you need to resolve the instance in a JsonConverter before the internal converter automatically creates one for you.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be the following:

1. Replace PreserveReferncesHandling from Objects to None:

```
    PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None
```

2. Add an Id property in Person class:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Person Mother { get; set; }
    }
```

The complete solution is as follows:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ControlJsonId
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("INICIO");
            var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
                Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
            };

            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => settings;

            var person = new Person
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Name = "bob",
                Mother = new Person { Id = string.Empty, Name = "jane" }
            };

            var personJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
            Console.WriteLine(personJson);

            var motherJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person.Mother);
            Console.WriteLine(motherJson);

            Console.WriteLine("FIN");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Person Mother { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
INICIO
{
  "Id": "76d6b5f0-2be8-4d1d-aafe-fe1b4b7d6ae1",
  "Name": "bob",
  "Mother": {
    "Id": "",
    "Name": "jane",
    "Mother": null
  }
}
{
  "Id": "",
  "Name": "jane",
  "Mother": null
}
FIN
```

Comment: For a better explanation. This link explains it well:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

Comment: Why did you put an ID property on the class and why did you arbitrarily assign it a GUID? I am not talking about a physical ID on the class. It's a meta ID that the JSON serializer adds to the JSON so that it knows how to preserve references when it deserializes.