# How to deserialize arrays with reference ids in a JSON using JSON.Net C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I know that JsonDotNet can deserialize a json taking care of reference ids. But I couldn't find a solution for a simple array with multiple room ids assigned to a tour (in my example). I set my (de)serializer settings to:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects };
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json, settings);
```

My model class looks like:

```
public class Tour
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
}

public class Room
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

}

And my example json like this:

```
{
  "tours":[
    {
      "$id":"luw5b23b",
      "name":"Tour 1",
      "rooms":[
        {
          "$ref":"k2j3hjh2"
        },
        {
          "$ref":"vg2345fg"
        },
        {
          "$ref":"nb2m5h2j"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rooms":[
    {
      "$id":"k2j3hjh2",
      "name":"Room 1"
    },
    {
      "$id":"vg2345fg",
      "name":"Room 2"
    },
    {
      "$id":"nb2m5h2j",
      "name":"Room 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunatelly the rooms are null. I'm a totally wrong and this is something I should process as ids and link objects after deserialization by myself or can JsonDotNet do that for me?

Please note, the object ids are provided by a system and should not generated or serialized by JsonDotNet.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868664/controlling-json-nets-reference-id-generation

Comment: Did you try to compare serialized result of expected object graph with your example json?

Comment: I think the main problem is the $refs come earlier in the JSON than the $ids they refer to.  So you would need two passes to resolve them.  Json.Net does not do two-pass deserialization.  If you can swap the order of the rooms and tours arrays in the JSON it *might* work.  I'm not sure about the alphanumeric ids though-- normally Json.Net uses numeric ids, so you might still need to implement an `IReferenceResolver`.

Comment: Json.NET's [default reference resolver](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultReferenceResolver.cs) is perfectly happy to resolve alphabetic ids.  However as @BrianRogers wrote, because Json.NET is a one-pass serializer the definition must always come before the reference.